# NSDictionary into a NSInputStream

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsinputstream

Is it possible to put in my NSDictionary into a NSInputStream?
This would be my NSDictionary

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"device_token", @"identifier", nil];
NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Test iPhone", initDeviceToken, [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier, nil];
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];
```

I tried something like this but it didn't worked...

```
NSInputStream *inputStream = [[NSInputStream alloc] init];
[inputStream setValue:@"123" forKey:@"identifier"];
```

Thx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  The way you can do it is serialize your dictionary into an `NSData` object using `NSPropertyListSerialization`, and then write your data object out to your `NSInputStream`.

The downside is that this requires that your dictionary only hold plist objects (numbers, strings, dates, data, arrays, and dictionaries).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Any object that conforms to the [NSCoding protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSCoding) is serializable and as such writable to a stream. Of course the items in a container object must also conform to the NSCoding protocol.